# Infinite loops in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, infinite-loop, strcmp, strcpy

I'm pretty sure this this piece of code gives me an infinite loop, (I have left if for a very long time and nothing happens), and I've been starring at this for 2 days now and i don't have a clue why it keeps looping. Any ideas?

```
    int r = 0;
    int H = 0;
    int g = 0;

    while (r < (3265920)) {

        while (g < 79338) {
            //printf("middle");
            if (!strcmp(arr1[g], Arr2[r])) {

            strcpy(out[H], arr1[g]);
            H++;
        }
            g++;
        }

    r++;
    g = 0;
}

Q=0;
while (Q < 79338) {


    printf("%d: %s\n",Q, Ans[Q]);
    Q++;

}
```

All the arrays have the correct memory allocation outside the main.

```
static char arr2[NINE_FACT * 9][10];
char Ans[79339][10];
char arr1[79339][45];
```

Comment: Properly indent. And use self-explanatory names. You have 3 loops. Which one do you mean? What does the debugge say? What have you tried yourself to find out (except for staring at it).

Comment: @J.doo  What does this magic number  3265920 mean and why are you using index beyond the array?

Comment: @J.doo  And what are arr2 and Arr2?

Comment: Cv as 'unclear'.  Full of magic numbers and missing declarations:(

Comment: Technically, your code could loop infinitely on a machine that only supported 16 bit `int` (the minimum size allowed by the C standard). But, overflow of signed integer is undefined anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner loop is running 259111560960 times that will likely take a long time. What is **H** being used for? On a 32 bit machine **H** could cause bugs because it's going to overflow. Note, the word length of the machine you're on is important ie what does this code produce on your machine?

```
printf("sizeof(int) == %zu\n", sizeof(int));
```

I'm surprised it runs properly.

```
out[H]; //This array could be huge.
```

If this is a normal array and you're on a 64bit machine I'd expect a segmentation fault or and this can sometimes take some time a Core Dump.

Assuming a 32bit machine and single characters as strings out[H] will require 2^31 bytes * 2 due to null terminator ie just over 4 Gb of RAM?

Comment: Does int type can handle such value?

Comment: depends on the machine @Joel

Comment: both r and g are being tested before they would overflow. The point is you are running strcmp and strcpy nearly 26 billion times. I don't know what "H" is being used for but if you are on a 32 bit machine it's going to overflow.

Comment: H is only incremented of two arrays are identical so it isn't added evrey time.

Comment: it's checking all possible permutations, (inc. all lengths) of a random 9 letter string against all words so they will not match more than 80,000 times

Answer (score 0):

value of `r`is never going to be 3265920 if it is 2 byte of memory allocation

either you change the datatype of `r to long` or change the condition of `r` so that it will be in the range of `int`

first u analyze the range of `int`